# Cannot access table in 2nd database from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, multiple-databases

I have 2 databases on a server:

- database1
- database2

I am trying to query a table in each database. However, when I try that, I get the following error:

> Unknown table 'database2.client' in field list

Here is the code that I am using in a script running on database 1:

```
SELECT database2.client.id;
```

It returns the unknown table error. The odd thing is that if I query for the databases, it shows them both:

```
SHOW DATABASES
```

it returns the following:

```
information_schema
database1
database2
```

I'm not sure why the SHOW syntax confirms that both databases are there, but I'm not able to select data from the other table.

Comment: Does the user under which you are running the queries on each database server?

Comment: what is database2.client.id? what is the '.id' ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you select it if you first run `use database2`, and then `SELECT client.id`?

**EDIT:**

As many people have pointed out, you need to use the correct `SELECT` syntax.

```
USE database2;
SELECT id FROM client;
```

Comment: this works but only with "SELECT id FROM client" - not SELECT client.id

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM database2.client;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT id FROM database2.client
```

Where `id` is the column, `database2` is your database, and `client` is your table.